# can't override "modal-slide.html"

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, template, overrides, html

I'm trying to override `modal-slide.html` in my base theme so I place that file at:

`app/design/frontend/<vendor>/base/Magento_Ui/web/templates/modal/modal-slide.html`

But Magento just won't pick it up. I also tried to place it in these folders:

`app/design/frontend/<vendor>/base/Magento_Ui/web/template/modal/modal-slide.html`

`app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<template>/web/template/modal/modal-slide.html`

`app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<template>/web/templates/modal/modal-slide.html`

Of course I redeploy static-content and flush caches (browser too). Other overrides work. Just that doesn't.
I never overwrote files from the `base` directory though.

How can I override that template?

Comment: Looking at where this file exists in the pub/static dir, perhaps the location needs to be: `app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Ui/templates/modal/modal-slide.html`. 

Compiled path I found in my code base: `pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_GB/Magento_Ui/templates/modal/modal-slide.html`

I Haven't tested this though!

Answer (score 0):

You should put your custom file in
**`app/design/frontend/[VendorName]/[theme]/Magento_Ui/web/templates/modal/modal-slide.html`**

Then, deploy static content

Comment: @BenCrook not always but you can delete the template files in pub/static

Comment: @Walish That's where I have put it.

Comment: Ohh I only just noticed it was a HTML file not PHTML. Yeah you're right about `pub/static`. I don't think clearing Magento cache even helps with static assets so I'll remove my comment.

Comment: @DarsVaeda Please take a closer look at your paths, they're not same as mine :)

Comment: I look several times to be sure ^^ How do they differ?

Comment: @DarsVaeda you missed [theme] dir in your path, `app/design/frontend/<vendor>/base/Magento_Ui/web/template/modal/modal-slide.html` is just close, not correct yet.

Comment: `base` is the theme name.

Comment: @DarsVaeda `templates` instead of `template`. I think that's all you need to update.

Comment: Nope that's not it, I've named it both.